# Problema al modificar el style de un elemento HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom, html-tabla

**Tengo un problema al intentar modificar el style de un elemento 
HTML desde Javascript.**

Lo que quiero hacer es ir cambiando la posición de un elemento *div* dependiendo de que tecla se haya accionado.

**El error que me sale es el siguiente:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at HTMLDocument.teclas (plataforma.html:27)

*Aquí el código fuente:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Cuadro magico</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Measurements:
        var top = 0, side = 0; 
        var box = document.getElementById("box");

        function teclas(event){
            var codigo = event.keyCode; //Get the key
            switch(codigo){ 
                case 32: //Move top
                    top--;
                    box.style.top = top + 'px';
                    break;
                case 40: //Move down
                    top++;
                    box.style.top = top + 'px';
                    break;
                case 37: //Move to left
                    side--;
                    box.style.left = side + 'px';
                    break;  
                case 39: //Move to right
                    side++;
                    box.style.left = side + 'px';
                    break;  
            }
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            document.onkeydown = teclas;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent"> <div id="box"></div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prueba incluyendo tu `var box` dentro del `window.onload`; puede ser que al momento de entrar en tu función onload, la variable box aun no se encuentra definida y por eso te lanza el error

Comment: hola amigo, sabes cual es la diferencia general de colocar el script en la cabecera y en el cuerpo? y de que forma se realiza el critical rendering path? podrías intentar colocar tu script al final del body, agregarle el atributo defer y manejar el evento DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Lo que dice @nauseantparrot, pero con un detalle: `defer` no funciona con código  inline, tendrías  que moverlo a un fichero aparte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver el problema que tienes, intenta mover tu `<script>` al final de `<body>`. Algo así:

```html
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script>...</script>
</body>
```

Ahora después de eso tendrás un problema con la variable `top`, pues JS asignara tu variable igual a un objeto `Window` en lugar de un entero. Para evitar eso, deberás cambiar el nombre de la variable por algo diferente, intenta `var topCoords = 0;`.

Finalmente podrías presentar un problema si tu `<div id="box">` no tiene el atributo `position` igual a `relative` el `<div>` no se moverá, pues se ocupan para utilizar las propiedades `top` y `left`.

**Aquí te dejo un snippet de como debería quedar tu código que podrás ejecutar y una breve explicación**

#### Ejemplo: (No tengo tu CSS, asi que me las arregle para hacer esto.)

```js
var topCoords = 0; sideCoords = 0; 
var box = document.getElementById("box");

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 32: // Move up
            topCoords--;
            box.style.top = topCoords + 'px';
            break;
        case 40: // Move down
            topCoords++;
            box.style.top = topCoords + 'px';
            break;
        case 37: // Move left
            sideCoords--;
            box.style.left = sideCoords + 'px';
            break;
        case 39:  // Move right
            sideCoords++;
            box.style.left = sideCoords + 'px';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    position: absolute;
}
#box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"> <div id="box"></div> </div>
```

#### Explicación

Renombre las variables `top` y `side` a `topCoords` y `sideCoords`. Esto porque al declarar `var top`, en lugar de tomar `top` como un entero, este lo tomaba como un Objeto `Window`.

Ahora, para verificar si el usuario a presionado alguna tecla, llame `document.onkeydown` y lo asigne a `function (e) {}`. Con `e.keyCode` obtengo el código de la tecla que se presiono. Ahora utilice tu lógica para mover el `<div>` nada mas que en lugar de llamar `top` y `side` llame `topCoords` y `sideCoords`.

Esto es para JS, en CSS hay unos aspectos importantes que tienes que cumplir para que esto funcione. Para empezar el padre del `<div>` debe tener como valor de `position: absolute;` y el `<div>` debe tener como valor de `position: relative`, esto para que podamos usar las propiedades `top` y `left`. Estos son los puntos importantes en CSS, lo demás solo es para mostrar el rectángulo.